# How to fix this is not a function nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I am following this article from medium https://blog.bitsrc.io/serverless-backend-using-aws-lambda-hands-on-guide-31806ceb735e

Everything works except when I attempt to add a record to the DynamoDB I get an error that say "this is not a function"

```
const AWS = require ("aws-sdk");

const client = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const uuid = require ("uuid");

module.exports.myHero = async (event) => {

    const data = JSON.parse(event.body);

    const params = {

        TableName: "myHeros",
        Item: {

            id: uuid(),
            name: data.name,
            checked: false
        }
    };

    await client.put(params).promise();

    return {

        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };
};
```

```
{
    "errorMessage": "client.put(...).promise is not a function",
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "stackTrace": [
        "module.exports.myHero (/var/task/create.js:30:27)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is your aws-sdk up to date?

Comment: Hi I am using the the aws-sdk 2.2.15

Comment: The current version is 2.521.0. Please update and then re-test. Version 2.2.15 was created in November 2015.

Comment: Thank you.  I actually thought I was using the latest version. Updating to Version 2.521.0 solved the issue.

Comment: I've added this as an answer. Please accept so that people know the problem has been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In almost all cases, when you call a method xyz() on an AWS client object and it fails with ‘xyz is not a function’, the problem is that you are using an old version of an SDK that does not actually support that method.

Upgrading to the latest AWS SDK version will fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

When initializing dynamodb client new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()' please pass options (at-least region parameter) to DocumentClient function.